# Send xml code to server using java?

Tags: java, xml

So, I'm curious.
How would one go about sending XML, such as,

```
<request>
<playerID>Name</playerID>
</request>
```

to a server, using Java.

Is there a predefined method that exists within the Java API, or something of that sort?
Does sending the above code *directly* differ from sending it inside of an external XML document?

I'm at a loss. I really hope this question is clear enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about [*SOAP*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)

You can do it with [*JAX-WS*](http://jax-ws.java.net/) simply, [*Here*](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html) is tutorial

Answer (score 2):

> **So, I'm curious. How would one go about sending XML**

Unless your bottleneck really is your bandwidth, I suggest you just send it as plain text similar to ordinary HTTP.

> **Is there a predefined method that exists within the Java API, or something of that sort?**

Not in the standard Java API.

> **Does sending the above code directly differ from sending it inside of an external XML document?**

Not sure what you mean here. Care to clarify?

Comment: To clarify, I could send the XML as "Code in a string" or, as code in an external XML document.

Comment: Can't see how sending it in an external xml document would gain anything.